# how do i import postgresql database from a local folder or host directory

Tags: postgresql, dump, phppgadmin

I have a .sql file on both my local computer and another one FTP to my host..
There is not tool in phppgdmin to import the file.
What is the easiest to import the data?

i have dedicated hosting, and puTTy terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the PostgreSQL instance is accessible from your machine, you can easily do this:

```
psql -h your_server your_databasename -f /path/to/yourfile.sql
```

If it is not, you can open a SSH connection (through Putty) with [port fowarding](http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html) from `127.0.0.1:5432` (or whatever is your PG port) to other port (could be 5432 if you don't have a PG server running locally), and them just use `psql` to import the dump:

```
psql -h localhost -p <other port> your_databasename -f /path/to/yourfile.sql
```

Another solution, is to send the file to the server and import from there. To send it, you can use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), that send files through a SSH connection.

One more thing, if your file is too big, you can check the "Enable compression" checkbox at "Connection > SSH" on Putty.

Comment: i receive this type or errors
`ERROR:  permission denied for language c
ERROR:  role "renzo" does not exist`

Comment: I would like to use this command when im connected via SSH to my server and import the SQL which is on my local machine, is there a way to do that without copying first the .sql on the server?